# Sharepoint 2010 People picker not working in Google Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, people-picker

I have a page with a custom webpart, the webpart has many fields and at the end it has a people picker.

The people picker popup opens correctly and I can select users inside, however they values selected are not returned to the textbox.

This only happens in Google Chrome, in Firefox and Internet explorer it works fine.

If I use the people picker in an edit form it works in all browsers. if I use the people picker in a popup it also works in all browsers.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Dev Tools Console (F12) ?

Comment: No, It does not show any errors

Comment: Show the code how do you develop that people picker

Comment: Is the default people picker of SP 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article from an ISV talks about the issue](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2014/11/chrome-v37-problem-changing-user-teamtime/) and traces it to a method Chrome no longer supports but for which the People Picker relies on.